# RDF Schema generation from RDF data instance

Tags: rdf, rdfs

Is anyone aware of some work being done on generating RDF schema for a given RDF data instance ? It would be some thing like coming up with information like classes, their attributes, their associations(hierarchical or peer) with other classes and if possible data types of attributes. It all resembles RDF Schema.

My other question is how different is this approach (RDF schema generation from a given RDF data instance) from finding patterns in RDF data ? Is it the same thing put up in a different way OR, is finding patterns a step further to schema generation and involves stuff like coming up with logical inferences (transitive relationships etc) from the class associations ?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New answer since i found somethin not reviewed and unrelated to what i wrote previously. I don't know how it works but i believe you're searching something like that: [vocabify](http://kwijibo.talis.com/vocabify/). See the [example](http://kwijibo.talis.com/vocabify/?sample)

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks a bunch florentjoc...This is something similar to what I'm looking for.

Comment: What is the value of Vocabify?  It doesn't actually provide any additional meaning.  It just declared what is already stated in the data.  I suppose if you are developing an ontology it's a minor time saver but the output of Vocabify by itself doesn't provide any useful meaning that can be used by a reasoning engine.

Comment: Could vocabify be used to determine incongruence rather than validation errors? i.e. a different perspective on schema alignment.

Comment: The links are down

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, i never heard of it. It sound strange anyway. what do you mean by generating the schema? Using RDFS already tell you few things like if you have some specific triples, you can infer others. E.g.

- ex:S ex:P ex:O ==> ex:P rdf:type rdf:property
- ex:A rdf:type ex:B ==> ex:B rdf:type rdf:class

and others.
But i'm not sure that's what you mean? do you mean statistical analysis to find group of instance, creates classes or find the range/domain of your properties?

For the patterns question, i know one project [DL-Learner](http://aksw.org/Projects/DLLearner) base on machine learning and OWL-DL reasoning. Not sure that's what you want once again.

Comment: From my first point I meant that I have an RDF data instance with me but I don't know the schema which generated it. So, I can have a black box which takes RDF data instance as input and gives the corresponding schema as output. Something like reverse engineering.

Comment: And you can't resolve the URI for the property/class used in your ABox(instances) data to get information on your TBox(schema)? I still don't get it. Are you speaking of an existing problem you have or more an hypothetic one?

Comment: I will try to clarify more. My approach doesn't take into account, naming the classes. I guess that needs to be done using a dictionary. May be some approach from Ontology needs to be used there.
My approach is to a generate schema structure that would have classes named as Class A and attributes.