# Populating RDFS Ontology from RDF data

Tags: rdf, ontology, rdfs

I am new to the ontology field. My question is a clarification one rather than a problem. 
The information that am dealing with is written in RDF format. I built my own RDFS ontology and I want to populate that ontology from the RDF data that I have. How can I do that with Jena ?? Does the naming of resources/properties need to be the same between RDF data and my RDFS ontology ?? Example is appreciated.

Also, the difference between RDF and RDFS is still not so clear to me. Can I consider RDF as an ontology but with limited capabilities (in encoding the knowledge) ??

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575979/rdf-schema-generation-from-rdf-data-instance and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755113/how-are-rdf-and-rdfs-related

Answer (score 3):

The RDFS triples define the meaning of the vocabulary of properties and classes (through `subClassOf` and `subPropertyOf` triples), while the RDF triples are just the data over which the RDFS metadata is applied.

Example, my metadata (RDFS) is

```
:Dog rdfs:subClassOf :Mammal
```

(which should be read as "Dogs are a sub set of Mammals or every Dog is also a Mammal"

and the data (RDF)

```
:Fido rdf:type :Dog
:Spike rdf:type :Dog
```

(should be read as Fido and Spike are elements of the set called "Dog")

The RDFS metadata defines your vocabulary of Classes and Properties, the data refers to those classes of properties.

A very nice reading about all data is in the "Semantic Web for the Working Ontologist", not to  theoretical and it does cover things in a comprehensive way.

Comment: but what about the first part of the question, do you have any idea of how to populate my RDFS ontology using the RDF data that I have. Thanks

Comment: First thought about populating an ontology from data: data mining. If you want to discover that some class is a subclass of another, or what the `rdfs:domain`s of certain properties are, you need to discover the relations between instances which is pretty much what data mining is about.